# Error when uploading from a Cloud Storage bucket to Google Colab using 'gsutil'

Tags: machine-learning, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-colaboratory, bucket

I've trained a model in a Compute Engine VM instance in GCP and copied the weights into a Cloud Storage bucket using the `gsutil cp -r` command.

I then made the bucket public and tried to copy those weights into a Google Colab notebook using the command `!gsutil cp -r gs://{bucket/folder} ./`

However, I get the following error:

> **ResumableDownloadException:** Transfer failed after 23 retries. Final
>   exception: Anonymous caller does not have storage.objects.get access
>   to {folder/path}

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: Is there a particular reason to use gs://{bucket/folder}  instead of gs://bucket/folder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Edit:

- The Cloud Storage bucket is missing the appropriate Cloud IAM role to
  make it fully publicly read from. The role
  [`roles/storage.objectViewer`](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-roles#standard-roles)
  provides the necessary permissions to read and list objects from the
  bucket - assigning it to `allUsers` will make it public.

  Therefore, as per the
  [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/making-data-public#buckets),
  this can be achieved with a single [`gsutil
  iam`](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/iam)
  command:

  `gsutil iam ch allUsers:objectViewer gs://[BUCKET_NAME]`.

  And then, in in Google Colab you should be able to read (or download) objects from Cloud Storage buckets with:

  `!gsutil cp -r gs://[BUCKET_NAME]/[FOLDER_NAME] ./`
- A safer approach is to instead of making the entire Cloud Storage
  bucket public, to authenticate with it using the following Python
  code in the notebook:

  `from google.colab import auth auth.authenticate_user()`

  Then set the **project ID** you're using with a `gcloud` command;
  replacing `my-project` accordingly:

  `!gcloud config set project my-project`

  And finally run the `gsutil` command; replacing `bucket` and
  `folder`:

  `!gsutil cp -r gs://[BUCKET_NAME]/[FOLDER_NAME] ./`

Comment: Thanks ! But I don't want to authenticate to it because I want to share the colab notebook with anyone who is not in the project or even someone who does not necessarily has a google account...

Comment: Plus, I tried those commands above with a google account which is not in the project and got  : AccessDeniedException: 403 HttpError accessing

Comment: @TahaMahjoubi How did you make the bucket public? To make Cloud Storage buckets completely public, (regardless if they use fine-grained or uniform access control) require an IAM role as well. In my case, assigning the Cloud IAM `objectViewer` role to `allUsers` as per the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/making-data-public#buckets) was enough, and I was able to get objects from it with just `!gsutil cp -r gs://{bucket/folder} ./`. Be aware though, that you're making the bucket publicly readable by doing so.

Comment: Thanks a lot I solved ! I used this command to make my bucket public : gsutil iam ch allUsers:objectViewer gs://[BUCKET_NAME]. But It only made my bucket public and not the objects inside. So I manually went to my bucket permissions and clicked on "new Members", added "AllUsers" and "AllAuthenticatedUsers" to "Storage **object** viewer" :)

Comment: @TahaMahjoubi Thanks for the heads up. Consider accepting the answer if it was helpful. For the benefit of the community and to attract more visibility. I'll update the answer with this second approach shortly.

Comment: `A safer approach` above works for me. thanks!